# Finding a generator of a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra

How can I find a generator of $\mathbb{F}_{743}[x]/(x^2+1)$ ?

(x-5) ??? Well it has something to do with primes that do not divide the order of 743 which is equal 2*7*53 ....?

Does one of you know how to do this?

Comment: Try $F_{743}[x]/(x^2+1)\simeq (\Bbb Z/743\Bbb Z)[i]$

Comment: So is $(x-i)$ a generator? How can be proven that $(x-i)$ has order 742 ?

Comment: $\left|(\Bbb Z/743 \Bbb Z)[i]\right|=N(743)=743^2$, so you're looking for an element with order $743^2-1$.  Also, $(\Bbb Z/743 \Bbb Z)[i]$ is not a polynomial ring, so you shouldn't have an $x$ in the elements... $\sqrt{-1}=i$ replaces $x$ since it's a root of $x^2+1$.  If you're not comfortable with the number theory you can just go back to the original problem.

Comment: Thank you but I still can not find a Generator of $\mathbb{Z}_{743} [i] $ either. What should that be? 1-i ? 1+i ?

Comment: How can one prove that the order of 1-i is 743^2-1 ?

If 1-i is not a generator... still the same question as you see above: How can now one find a generator?

Comment: It turns out that $2+i$ is one of the generators. See my answer to the duplicate.