# Finding Generator of finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, finite-fields

The task is to show that $x^2 + 1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_{743}$ and then find a generator of  $\mathbb{F}_{743}[x]/(x^2+1)$.

This question has already been asked but not really answered 
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585400/finding-a-generator-of-a-finite-field)

I've shown that $x^2+1$ is irreducible, since $ 743 \equiv 3\pmod{4}$ and therefore $-1$ is not a quadratic residue mod 743.

But I don't understand how to find a generator of $\mathbb{F}_{743}[x]/(x^2+1)$. I assume I need to look for an element of order $743^2-1$, but is there an obvious way to do this, or is it just done by trying?

Comment: Yes, try elements $\alpha$ in the field (say $\alpha=x$ or $\alpha=x+1$) and check what $\alpha^{n \over 2}$ is where $n=743^2 - 1$. If it is $-1$ we have a generator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are particularly persistent software assistance is recommended. Educated guessing does help, so I will share my approach. A bit of divide and conquer. I saw this as an exercise in trying to minimize computer aid, but you are welcome to have mixed feelings about the wisdom of that :-)

The main observation is that in a cyclic group of order $n$ an element $g$ is a generator unless $g^{n/p}=1$ for some prime $p\mid n$.

First we probably want a generator of $K=\Bbb{F}_{743}$. The law of quadratic reciprocity says that both $2$ and $3$ are squares in this field but $5$ is not, so let's test $5$ more carefully. Here $n=742=2\cdot7\cdot53$, and because $5$ is not a square $5^{n/2}\neq1$. We do need to check the exponents $n/7=106$ and $n/53=14$. Mathematica (or Wolfram Alpha) tells me that
$$
5^{14}\equiv212\pmod{743}\qquad\text{and}\qquad 5^{106}\equiv 433\pmod{743},
$$
so we can conclude that $5$ is a generator of $K^*$.

We move on to the extension field $L=K[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$. For easier notation I will denote the coset of $x$ modulo $x^2+1$ by $i$ so the familiar rule $i^2=-1$ holds. Another piece of theory is the use of automorphisms. Clearly "complex conjugation" $a+bi\mapsto a-bi$ is a non-trivial automorphism of $L$. But we also know that the Frobenius automorphism is the only non-trivial automorphism of a quadratic extension of the prime field. Therefore, for all $a,b\in K$ we have
$$
(a+bi)^{743}=a-bi.
$$ 
It follows that 
$$
(2+i)^{744}=(2+i)^{743}(2+i)=(2-i)(2+i)=5.
$$
This already gives us a reason so suspect that $g=2+i$ might be a generator of $L^*$.
The order of $L^*$ is $N=742\cdot744=2^4\cdot3\cdot7\cdot31\cdot53$, so we have five primes to consider. Let us denote the order of $g$ by $m$. We know that the order
of $g^{744}$ is $742$. On the other hand, if $c$ is an element of order $\ell$
in a multiplicative, it is well known that (covered in a first course on cyclic groups)
$$
\operatorname{ord}(c^k)=\frac{\ell}{\gcd(\ell,k)}.
$$
Together with the known order $742$ of $g^{744}$ we see that
$$
2\cdot7\cdot53=742=\frac{m}{\gcd(m,744)}.
$$
This implies that $m$ is divisible by both $7$ and $53$, so we don't need to test those primes.

Could it be that $g^{N/p}=1$ for any of the remaining prime factors $p\in\{2,3,31\}$ of $N$? An element $z\in L^*$ has order that is a factor of $742$ if and only if $z\in K^*$. If $g^{N/31}=1$ it follows that the order of $g^{744/31}=g^{24}$ must be a factor of $742$. In other words, for this to happen we must have $g^{24}\in K$.
But a calculation modulo $743$ shows that
$$
(2+i)^{24}=302+357i\notin K.
$$
Similarly, $g^{N/3}=1$ implies that $g^{744/3}=g^{248}\in K$. Again, a calculation
shows that
$$
(2+i)^{248}=-237-251i\notin K.
$$
The last prime factor $p=2$ is shared by $742$ and $744$. Therefore it is easy for
$$
(2+i)^{N/2}=(2+i)^{744\cdot(742/2)}=5^{742/2}.
$$
We already knew that $5$ is a generator $K^*$, so this power is not trivial (in fact, it must be equal to $-1$).

> Conclusion: $2+i$ is a generator of $L^*$. Aided by a bit of algebra we managed to keep the set of exponents we had to test a bit lower. Not sure whether the tricks brought the exponents to a range, where you might be willing to paper & pencil calculate them, for example by the good old square-and-multiply.

Comment: An alternative would be to use algebra to locate roots of unity of orders $3$, $31$ and $16$ within the extension field. Together with $5^2$ known to have order $742/2$ the product of all these would be a generator. There are a total of $\phi(743^2-1)=149760$ generators. Not much reason to prefer one of the other, but I do think $2+i$ is among the simplest to describe :-)

Comment: Henno's trial-and-error approach has success rate a bit less than $1/3$. I take a little bit of pride in the fact that after spotting $5$ as a generator for the prime field I only needed a single trial :-)

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm is probabilistic: try elements $\alpha$ of $\Bbb F_{743}[x]{/}(x^2+1)$ and check if $\alpha^{\frac{n}{2}} = -1$, where $n=|\Bbb F^\ast_{743}[x]{/}(x^2+1)|=743^2 - 1 = 552048$. If this holds we've found our generator.

Some computer assistance seems required. (Pari or some such program). (I normally start with $\alpha=x$ as a try, next, maybe $x+1$ or $x-1$ etc.)

Comment: This is not sufficient. For if $x=\alpha$ satisfies $x^{n/2}=-1$ so does $x=\alpha^3$. But $3$ is a factor of $n=2^4\cdot3\cdot7\cdot31\cdot53$, so $\alpha^3$ will never be a generator. A correct test is to check that $\alpha^{n/p}\neq1$ for all prime factors $p\mid n$. The chances of a random non-zero element being a generator is a bit below one in three. We need to throw out both squares and cubes (= two thirds) as well as a bit of other stuff corresponding to other prime factors.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You're quite right of course, I forgot about it because usually I consider $F_p$ fields where $p$ is a safe prime, so $p=2q+1$ where $q$ is prime, and then only the power $q$ check is needed (and the square of course). But when $p-1$ has other factors it's a bit more work..

Comment: I see. That is, indeed, a special case. Now that you brought it up, I recall having used Sophie Germain prime pairs as examples for this very reason.